# A macro with quotes around a metavariable

Tags: rust

I want to println! a macro identifier, (mostly for testing macros), but if I do it like this:

```
macro_rules! printname(
(
    $name:ident;
) => (
    println!("$name");
)

let this_name = "hello";

printname!(this_name);
```

it just prints

> $name

and if i do `println!("{}", $name);` it of course substitutes in the variable `this_name` and prints

> hello

What I actually want it to do is print

> this_name

Is there a way to quote a metavariable to get its value?

Answer (score 9):

The [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify!.html) macro should work. It provides a string representation of the passed argument as a `&'static str`, which can then be passed directly into `println!` to print it to stdout.